# Check if a value is in a list of numbers

Tags: vbscript

Say I have a group of numbers 23,56,128,567 and I have to apply a conditional logic in which if a variable `myData` exists in the above group of numbers then only I proceed, otherwise I don't.

Sorry, have to look into some legacy code and not exactly sure how to do it in VBScript.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could put the values in a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29):

```
Set list = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
list.Add  23, True
list.Add  56, True
list.Add 128, True
list.Add 567, True
```

and then check if your value exists in the dictionary:

```
If list.Exists(myData) Then
  'do stuff
End If
```

An [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be another option:

```
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
list.Add 23
list.Add 56
list.Add 128
list.Add 567

If list.Contains(myData) Then
  'do stuff
End If
```

Comment: I implement it and it works but it throws an Active X warning

Comment: @user3637345 Please post a new question with your implementation and the exact error message.

Answer (score 5):

**Serenity**'s idea isn't so bad, you just have to make sure you use the right separators on both strings.

For example:

```
If instr("|23|56|128|567|","|" & myData & "|") then ...
```

should work just fine with no false positives

Comment: This was a clean, easy solution that worked for me.  It took me a second to realize what was going on, but then I realized you simply book-end each value and the variable with bars.  If Bars are in your search, then simply use a different separator character.  TY!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a select case :

```
Select case myData
    case 23,56,128,567 
       ' do your stuff ...
End Select
```

Answer (score -4):

```
If instr("23,56,128,567", myData) then ...
```

As this is vbscript this should work.

Comment: No. This will give false positives for values like `5` or `12`.

Comment: If instr("23,56,128,567", "," & myData & ",")

Comment: That will give false negatives for `23` and `567`.

Comment: It may, but people know their inputs, my pattern is commonly used for command line parsing. So my pattern is correct based ondata, not your critism's based on unknown tests. The other soultions will usually be overkill.

Comment: Your approach is flawed and will produce incorrect results. Period.

Comment: A real world example `For X = LBound(cmdlinefile) To UBound(cmdlinefile):If InStr(1, LCase(cmdlinefile(X)), LCase(" -embedding"), vbTextCompare) > 1 Then:
        ElseIf (InStr(1, LCase(cmdlinefile(X)), LCase(" -p"), vbTextCompare) > 1) Or (InStr(1, LCase(cmdlinefile(X)), LCase(" /p"), vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
        ElseIf (InStr(1, LCase(cmdlinefile(X)), LCase(" -goto:"), vbTextCompare) > 1) Or (InStr(1, LCase(cmdlinefile(X)), LCase(" /goto:"), vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
        ElseIf Len(cmdlinefile(X)) > 0 Then
            gOpenFileName = cmdlinefile(X)
        End If
    Next
`